# MS-Access get superset strings in same column

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to get all strings inside a column that have other strings in the same column they are subset (that starts from the first character) of.

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT d.str FROM table1 d WHERE
d.str IN (SELECT dt.str FROM str dt 
    WHERE dt.str LIKE d.str & '*' AND d.str <> dt.str )
```

but it returns no results (i'm assuming because of the d.str <> dt.str).

Is there any other way to achieve this?

As an example, using the table:

```
|a  |
|ab |
|ac |
|acd|
|acm|
|e  |
|ef |
```

I want to get

```
|a  |
|ac |
|e  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using IN, use EXISTS:

```
    SELECT d.str FROM table1 d 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT dt.str FROM table1 dt 
    WHERE dt.str LIKE d.str & '*'  AND d.str <> dt.str )
```

Comment: It worked, but aren't they effectively the same thing?

Comment: Similar but different.  You should always use EXISTS whenever possible over IN.  IN is much slower and essentially re-queries the outer query for each record.